# The dropdown list is very small all other fonts are perfect in size

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried ctrl+ and ctrl- but it didn't help. I also tried uninstalling vs code

[image]

Comment: There are several different font-size settings in VSCode, can you be more specific, or post a screen shot of which drop-down is too small?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing C++ extension from [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) link and restart your VS Code once after installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the `editor.suggestFontSize` setting.  Its default is 0, which when 0, uses the `editor.fontSize` value instead.  Check both of these settings, but I am guessing your `editor.suggestFontSize` is set to something small, such as 2.

[image: Setting]